# Contempt of court in "Roman J. Israel, Esq."

Tags: realism, roman-j-israel-esq

In the legal drama film "Roman J. Israel, Esq.", the protagonist attorney is fined $5,000 for court contempt because, during a preliminary hearing, he claimed that the civil rights of his client had been violated and he continued to pursue that after the judges told him that he can address that at trial. Part of the scene is even in the movie trailer.

The transcript is the following:

> **Roman:** Objection. Motion to strike. Mr. Ramirez was told he was not under arrest and was interrogated without his Miranda warning, yet he was refused use of the bathroom. That is a violation of civil rights.
>
> **Judge:** Overruled.
>
> **Roman:** If a cop hauls you in and says you can't use the bathroom, then you're being detained...
>
> **Judge:** We are moving on...
>
> **Roman:** What was he supposed to do, pee himself?
>
> **Judge:** You can address this at trial.
>
> **Roman:** I would like to address it now. I'm just saying we have a real...
>
> **Judge:** Mr. Israel. Did you hear what I said?
>
> **Roman:** If armed guards in this courtroom detained you and would not allow you to use the bathroom you would be detained. What is good for the goose is good for the gander.
>
> **Judge:** I'm gonna hold you in contempt if you pursue this.
>
> **Roman:** With respect, you're asking me to obey an erroneous court decision.
>
> **Judge:** Find you in contempt.

Is this legal? And if so, would such decision make sense or would actually be easily overturned in appeal/cause problems to the judge/court... in other words, something a real judge would not do.

Comment: Finding one of the lawyers in contempt like this (especially for something so minor) effectively means that Roman will have to pay a fine for ignoring the judge's instructions.  This has no bearing whatsoever on the actual case, and Roman is still free to bring up the bathroom thing at the *real trial,* so there's nothing to appeal.

Comment: @Steve-O If Roman wants to overturn the judge's decision to deny the motion to strike (as opposed to the contempt finding) he needs to do that through an appeal, and this could have a major impact on the trial. For example if he was trying prevent a confession from being entered as evidence, he can still try convince the jury that the confession was coerced, but it would be better for the defence if the jury never heard it in the first place.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Obligatory disclaimer: I am not a lawyer.

In court, the judge's word is law. Literally. The decisions they make at the end of a trial form the legal precedent for later, similar trials. If you disrespect the authority of the judge, you are **disrespecting the authority of the court**, and by extension, disrespecting the law. This is what "contempt of court" means.

The specific law governing this in the USA is [Title 18 of the US Code, § 401](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/401) (emphasis mine):

> **A court of the United States shall have power to punish by fine or imprisonment**, or both, at its discretion, **such contempt of its authority**, and none other, as—
>   (1) Misbehavior of any person in its presence or so near thereto as to obstruct the administration of justice;
>   (2) Misbehavior of any of its officers in their official transactions;
>   **(3) Disobedience or resistance to its lawful writ, process, order, rule, decree, or command.**

The third one is why Roman was found in contempt. The judge overruling Roman's objection was a clear order that he should stop pursuing his point. Roman ignored them and continued. The judge then told him to stop on four further occasions, even outright telling him he would be in contempt of court if he continued, but Roman persisted, so eventually the judge had no choice but to find him in contempt.

The judge's actions were perfectly legal and sensible. Roman was quite clearly in contempt of court, and should have argued that point at trial as the judge suggested. As for whether the fine could be overturned, I really can't say. Again, I am not a lawyer.

Comment: Yep, you nailed this one.

Comment: Anecdotal supporting evidence: I was recently on Jury Duty and the judge told us we were to *exclusively* use his definition of the relevant laws for the duration of the trial.  We were, in fact, *explicitly prohibited* from looking up any other definitions of these laws - even in actual law books.  Also, one of the lawyers nearly got charged with contempt for calling one of the witnesses "bud" (as in "buddy") during questioning. He apologized *really quickly,* but you should've *seen* the look on the judge's face.  I can only assume these two had a history.

Comment: OK, this answer is quite satisfactory, but before I mark it I would like some reference to the laws. I'm from Europe, and here a judge fining an attorney is not so common.

Comment: @ReginaldKincaid Added the relevant law. I'm European too, but honestly, a lot of what I know about legal systems comes from US TV shows. Apparently you can even be jailed for contempt of court in the US, which I'm sure would be unheard of here.

Comment: @F1Krazy Not wanting to derail this thread but there was a high profile imprisonment for contempt just this week: Tommy Robinson.

Comment: @Steve-O: That is a disgusting practice, given that judges often instruct juries with their interpretation of the statute, which may differ from what the words in the statute actually say.  A defendant should be acquitted if there is any reasonable way of reading a statute such that the defendant's conduct would be legal, even if it would also be possible to read it as prohibiting the conduct in question.

Comment: @supercat It's an especially disgusting practice given that the entire motivation to create the jury system in the first place was to prevent unreasonable laws and/or unreasonable interpretations of laws from being enforced.

Comment: @supercat -- if the judge's instructions to the jury are incorrect and the defendant is convicted the conviction can be overturned on appeal. You're right that a law that doesn't clearly prohibit particular behavior can't be used to punish that behavior, and instructions to the jury should reflect that.

Comment: @supercat Are you a lawyer? "A defendant should be acquitted if there is any reasonable way of reading a statute such that the defendant's conduct would be legal" sounds like you could never judge anyone guilty, since any law can be read in many reasonable ways. If there is consistent jurisidiction on how the law is to be interpreted, it doesn't (where I live) matter if you could, in principle, read the letter of the law differently.

Comment: @ReginaldKincaid When you say "Europe", do you mean "Continental Europe"?  Most of Europe uses Civil (or Roman) Law, which has a rather different role for judges.  (Most of) the US uses Common Law (which it inherited from England);  Common Law makes the judge *much* more powerful - in fact "common law" is also known as "judge-made law".  (And, of course, even in Common Law systems, judges don't fine attorneys in real life because in real life they would stop).

Comment: @supercat Exactly what Pete Becker said.  In fact, the judge said as much himself.  The reason we are to use his interpretation only is because his interpretation *is part of the public record for this trial.*  If it's mistaken, others can find that mistake and use it to appeal.  On the other hand, if the jury is allowed to use whatever interpretation they find, their verdict may not be correct, and there would be no way to prove that.  (Even law books can have typos, after all.)

Comment: Not to mention that any judge worth his salt is going to be familiar with the laws as written anyway (it is his job, after all.)  He will certainly be more familiar with what's written than any juror, who are literally just people off the street.  They're not even lawyers (lawyers are prohibited from being jurors themselves because, as perceived experts, their opinion could influence the rest of the jury unfairly.)

Comment: @sgf: If a judge's interpretation indicates that a defendant is not guilty, then a jury would be duty-bound to acquit the defendant.  It, however, the judge's interpretation says guilt but the statute could be interpreted otherwise, the jury should acquit (and there would be no need to preserve a record for appeal).  If an appeals court finding that a judge's instructions were erroneous would result in a retrial, with the original errant trial court judge personally reimbursing the defendant for his time, legal fees, and other expenses, blindly following a judge's instruction might be okay...

Comment: @sgf: ...but of course that's not how things work.  As it is, if an appeals court may find that a judge's instructions were improper but a reasonable jury given proper instructions *might* have found the defendant guilty, the conviction will likely stand whether or not the actual jury, given proper instructions, *would* have found the defendant guilty.  And of course even if the defendant does get a retrial, the defendant would likely have had to suffer time in prison while waiting for the conviction to be overturned.  Better to have the jury acquit in the first place.

Comment: @Steve-O: See my comment to sgf.  Also, judge's view on what statutes say is often colored by other judge's interpretations of how they should be applied in other cases whose details might differ from the one at hand.  If there's a detail in the way a statute is worded which was genuinely irrelevant in any earlier cases, and other courts have ignored it for that reason, a judge might follow their lead even if the different facts of the present case would render it important.

Comment: @Steve-O: Personally, I think the system needs to have a better way for juries to ask questions and make statements on the record.  Appeals court judges are wont to guess whether a jury would have convicted if they'd seem some evidence they were denied, or hadn't seen some evidence they should have.  If the jury asks a judge a straight up question and the judge gives an answer that is legally wrong, the fact that the jury asked the question should create a presumption that the answer may have affected their decision.